# the error occurs when I use custom textview in the android studio

Tags: java, android

The code below is the custom textview class using the trebuchet font.

```
public class TrebuchetTextView extends TextView {

    public TrebuchetTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public TrebuchetTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public TrebuchetTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), getContext().getString(R.string.normal_font_path));
        setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
```

This is used in other app and works well.

But the inflation error occurs when I use custom textview in the my application.
I included the trebuchet font in the assets/fonts folder.

Comment: share your error with question

Comment: If you just want to change the typeface of all TextView's of app, you can use another approach.

Comment: Use custom textview with its full package path in xml file. Also this must be `getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.normal_font_path)`

Comment: `the inflation error occurs ` then you should fix it. But since you didn't tell which error, didn't show it's stacktrace - good luck fixing it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code for custom `textview`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontTextView extends TextView {


    public FontTextView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
      this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
  this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Helvetica_Neue.ttf"); 
  this.setTypeface(face); 
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


    }

}
```

and in xml:

```
<com.util.FontTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/accountInfoText"
                    android:textColor="#727272"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this your custom `textview` with its full package path in your layout.xml file like this

```
<com.example.pkg.TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**and change this line in your customtextview**

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "yourfont.ttf");
```